# Prove logical equivalence....almost finished, but....!

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have almost finished, but I'm stuck at one place. Please guide.

**Here is what I did:**

Q. (¬p v q) ∧ (p ∧ (p ∧ q)) ⇔ p ∧ q

(¬p v q) ∧ ((p ∧ p) ∧ q) **using Associative Law**

(¬p v q) ∧ (p ∧ q) **using idempotent Law**

?

How to remove (¬p v q)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some basic laws to rewrite $(\neg p\lor q)\land(p\land q)$ as

$$\big((\neg p\lor q)\land q\big)\land p$$

and show that $(\neg p\lor q)\land q$ is equivalent to $q$. How you do this will depend on exactly what laws you have available. It’s immediate if you have the absorption laws. Alternatively, you may have basic propositions $T$ and $F$ (or $1$ and $0$, or $\top$ and $\bot$) such that $q$ is equivalent to $F\lor q$. Then you can use a distributive law to change $(\neg p\lor q)\land(F\lor q)$ to $(\neg p\land F)\lor q$ and thence to $F\lor q$ and finally $q$.

Comment: Thanks! one question that I think, you probably wrote (¬p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∧ q) as ( (¬p ∨ q) ∧ q ) ∧ p using the Distributive Rule, but I think we can only use the distributive rule when it is like this for example in this case  (¬p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∧ q) should have been  (¬p ∧ q) ∧ (p ∧ q) to use it. But you used it for  (¬p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∧ q) as well. I might be wrong, but please clarify.

Comment: Or can you clarify which basic rules you used for this ( (¬p ∨ q) ∧ q ) ∧ p and how? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GhostRider: The only place that I explicitly used a distributive law was where I mentioned it near the end. Try using commutative and associative laws to do the rewriting mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do but wasn't able to do so. If you don't mind, can you kindly tell me exactly how you used these laws for **( (¬p ∨ q) ∧ q ) ∧ p** with steps? Million Thanks!

Comment: @GhostRider: You have something like $s\land(p\land q)$. Use commutativity inside the parentheses, and then use associativity, and you’ll have $(s\land q)\land p$, which is what you want.

Comment: Yeah! I did it. All credits to you. So, basically, you removed the importance of (¬p ∨ q) by assuming s = (¬p ∨ q). Even if we didn't assume it, we nevertheless neglected the operator ∨ in (¬p ∨ q). I'm wondering won't it violates the associative law now and by which law we ignored (¬p ∨ q) operator? as you made it look likes **s ∧ (p ∧ q)** for the associative law to be applied. This is real confusion. Much appreciated!

Comment: @GhostRider: You’re very welcome. It took me a while, but I finally realized that it was probably the fact that $\neg p\lor q$ was a compound proposition that was getting in your way.

Comment: Yeah, exactly! so, you agree that it is perfectly valid to alter and ignore any compound propositions like this in order solve our problem?

Comment: @GhostRider: Yes, any compound proposition within a larger compound proposition can be treated as a single entity. When you’re just beginning, it may be helpful actually to make a named substitution, as I did with $s$ for $\neg p\lor q$; with practice this becomes unnecessary.