# Using Proposition laws, how can we write (¬p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∧ q) as ( (¬p ∨ q) ∧ q ) ∧ p?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can anyone kindly tell me Using the Proposition laws step by step, how can we write **(¬p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∧ q)** as **( (¬p ∨ q) ∧ q ) ∧ p**? Much appreciated!

Comment: You really should not have made this a separate question; rather, you should have asked me to go into more detail [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1922078/12042). But I really think that you should first spend a little more time thinking about the suggestion in my last comment. It may help if you temporarily give $\neg p\lor q$ its own name, say $s$, and try to use that suggestion to get from $s\land(p\land q)$ to $(s\land q)\land p$.

Comment: The operator $\land$ is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) and [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).This mean that is the same to write $(p\land q)\land r$ that $p\land (r\land q)$ or $r\land q\land p$, and so on.